# Does "costwise" qualify as a word

Tags: adjectives, british-english, hyphenation, is-it-a-word, compounds

I'm translating a document into English, and the sentence structure is tempting me to use the word *costwise* in the sentence.

Example: "high-quality, **costwise** competitive services." This would refer to services that are of high quality and are also competitive with regard to cost (cf. competitive with regard to *quality* or *availability*).

Does *costwise* qualify as a word? Would it be spelled that way in British English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Costwise* **does** qualify as word, because the *-wise* suffix is productive; that is, adding *-wise* forms an adjective or adverb of manner. Dictionaries often don't individually list words formed by productive affixes.

Where the resulting word is awkward, like *security-wise,* which is [actually quoted in Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-wise), it can be hyphenated. Hyphens are gradually going out of fashion, particularly in simpler words where the components are readily identifiable like *costwise*. As ODO states, "most of the words so formed are considered inelegant or not good English style."

There is an issue with its placement in the sentence, though. *Costwise* is not an adverb which can precede the adjective it qualifies: it must occur after it. This applies to most, if not all, *-wise* adverbs.

> high-quality, competitive services costwise.

This is what makes it "inelegant, not good style".

In this example, you are describing that the services are competitive on cost, so you could simply form a compound adjective:

> high-quality, cost-competitive services

This has the effect of coining a little bit of business jargon, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Thank you. I will change it to cost-competitive, which says what it needs to say and fits the context perfectly.

Comment: Usually one would say "competitively priced".

Answer (score 1):

As far as strict rules go, costwise is not a word since it's not recognized by any dictionary.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=costwise

However adding a hyphen and writing cost-wise makes it grammatically correct and conveys the message.

Comment: Andrew’s surely right, affix-wise.

‘cost-competitive services’ trumps ‘competitive services costwise’. ‘Competitive services, costwise’ might lie between them if the new comma didn’t clash, as in ‘high-quality, competitive services, costwise’

If the object is not just to find a suitable phrase but specifically to justify using ‘costwise’, what would be wrong with ‘high-quality, costwise-competitive services’ or ‘high-quality services,  costwise-competitive’ or ‘high-quality services the are competitive, costwise’?

For further examples, see Peter Sellars’ *The Mouse on The Moon*  1963.